# Difference between split(' ') and split_whitespace()

Tags: rust

The following code prints out:

1
a
2
a

I don't get this. why does this happen?

```
fn main() {
    let s = "a ";
    let sv1:Vec<&str> = s.split_whitespace().collect();
    println!("{}", sv1.len());
    for x in sv1.iter() {
        println!("{}", x);
    }

    let sv2:Vec<&str> = s.split(' ').collect();
    println!("{}", sv2.len());
    for x in sv2.iter() {
        println!("{}", x);
    }
}
```

Comment: `str::split_whitespace` not only splits string by whitespace `char`, but also uses `filter` to reject all empty results. You can clearly see this at rust [std docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/str/mod.rs.html#793)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [the method docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.split_whitespace), `split_whitespace` returns [std::str::SplitWhitespace](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.SplitWhitespace.html), which is *An iterator over the non-whitespace substrings of a string, separated by any amount of whitespace.* which means it can split on multiple whitespaces, and doesn't include empty string in the result.

While for [`split` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.split),
*Contiguous separators are separated by the empty string.* as well as *Separators at the start or end of a string are neighbored by empty strings.*

So in your example,  `split_whitespace` gives `["a"]` but `split` gives `["a", ""]`.